# Grails - Save a svg image in the project public folder as JPG image

Tags: image, grails, svg, base64

I have a Groovy/Grails web app and I need to save a SVG image in the public folder of the my project (web-app/images/upload) as an image (JPG, PNG). So how I can do that?

Now I can convert SVG to base64, I think is easier save a base64 than save a SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Batik library](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/). 
[This](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2012/12/Batik-Convert-SVG-PNG-Java-Program-Example.html) looks like a fine example and nicely explained.